# Is there any difference between default scp and PuTTY pscp (with -scp) protocols?

Tags: ssh, putty, scp

I'm trying to automate a task that requires remote file transfer. The file provider manual specifically says that It needs a pscp (PuTTY version of scp) call to be made, and also already includes the pscp binary so we can use it. However, since most of the automation will be done on a java based service, I was wondering if I could use sshj or jsch, using the default ssh protocol.

So, do you know if pscp uses exactly the same protocol as plain old scp? I've just tried to move a couple of files using pscp and scp. Both worked, but I don't know if there are minor details that I'm not aware of (performance, security etc)

Answer (score 1):

> ... if there are minor details that I'm not aware of (performance,
> security etc)".

There are none. [`scp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol) (Secure CoPy) is a protocol and command line utility for secure file transfer; and [`pscp`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) is just the name of PuTTy SCP/SFTP client. The security of SCP is provided by SSH, which is used for data transfer and authentication.

The fact that the file provider manual already includes `pscp` is just a nice gesture from whoever is responsible for creating it. It being specified in the manual signifies that the creator usually deals with Windows users. Unlike UNIX- and Linux-based systems (including MacOS), until Win 10 Windows OS used to not have an SCP client.